# Why doesn't this CSS Full Height Layout display properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Update**:
I'm awarding a bounty of 50 to whoever can help me achieve [**this design**](http://sopranowebdesign.com/sfaa/example.jpg).

---

So I've been trying for the past 2-3 hours to fix this but can't seem to do it. Maybe someone with CSS or jquery experience can help me. I'm trying to [**accomplish this**](http://sopranowebdesign.com/sfaa/example.jpg). This is [**my result**](http://sopranowebdesign.com/sfaa/). Problem is that when I resize the browser window, column B's content gets cut off and there's an extra white space on the left of column A. [Here's a **screenshot** of what I mean](http://sopranowebdesign.com/sfaa/example2.jpg) to save you the time.

**CSS:**

```
#public {
  width:100%;
}
#public #container {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  min-width:1050px;
}
#public .left {
  float:left;
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
}
#public .left .content {
  float:right;
  width:365px;
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
#public .left .platforms {
  margin-top:40px;
}
#public .left .aila {
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
}
#public .left .copy {
  margin-top:20px;
  color:#171515;
  font:bold 12px Arial, Verdana;
}
#public .right {
  float:right;
  width:60%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#public .right .content {
  float:left;
  width:665px;
  min-height:704px;
  margin-top:20px;
  background:url(images/public-right-shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="public">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="" class="logo" />
        <img src="images/supported-platforms.png" class="platforms" />
        <div class="copy">&copy; all right reserved 2012</div>
      </div>
    </div><!--.left-->
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
      Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. 
      </div>
    </div><!--.right-->
  </div><!--#container-->
</div><!--#public-->
```

Comment: Try removing the "position" property from your #containers css definition. Also, the "top" and "left" properties may as well go if you do that. I don't think you need them to achieve what you want.

Comment: Actually, if you remove the absolute positioning I don't think any of the rules in #container's definition should be there. The width and height won't have any effect since height will only work if its parent element has a set height, and width will automatically be 100% for block elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if I remove those properties, the background-image won't go all the way to the bottom. Also, it has no effect on my problem.

Comment: You should create a jsfiddle for your issue to make it easier to examine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some simple adjustments for you and as far as I can tell it's working as per the image you attached in your question. See http://joshdavenport.co.uk/staging/swd/.

The differences are:

```
#public #container {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;

    min-width: 960px;
}
```

This `min-width` adjustment allows your design to fit tighter to the left when reducing the size of the page.

```
#public .right .content {
    /* change padding value to whatever feels right */
    padding-right: 10px;
    float:left;
    /* this loses the fixed size though */
    min-height:704px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background:url(images/public-right-shadow.png) no-repeat left top;

    width: 510px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
```

}

The `width` here ensure this element stays the same width all of the time and the `padding` ensures it stays away from the left area. You'll probably want to tweak this.

Answer (score 2):

i dont seem to replicate the same output , however, to me it seems that Your problem is in those width values of both Your content class objects.You have two relatively sized objects,specific values are 40% and 60% of Your window size.,but inside these , You have absolute width values (365px and 665px).Because Your screenshot resolution is 1,076px × 784px,
this means that Your right column , the #public .right , is cut at about 600+- px of width , however You are putting 665px width inside it.Which almost certainly overflows your wraping object.Therefor creating valid space for the runaway text. For Your overflowing text problem i would look for the problem there.

Now for the extra space on left side of Your #public .left this probably occurs because You are floating its content to the right side.

But as I said , i cant duplicate the same outcome.So if tinkering with that doesnt fix Your problem , feel free to ask more.

EDIT:
To Your Right Side problem , even though you support 1030px width ind your

> min-width:1050;

Your

> public .right

gets from that at max 630 , but in that You are trying to fit 665px

This code should fix Your issue

```
#public .right .content {
  /* change padding value to whatever feels right */
padding-right: 10px;
float:left;
 /* this loses the fixed size though */
width:100%;
min-height:704px;
margin-top:20px;
background:url(images/public-right-shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
 }
```

Comment: just edited and added some code for you , let me know if it works for Your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look dude. I've updated the code and it's the same issue and also I need the right content to be a fixed size. Maybe I'm going about this backwards and I need a better solution...

Comment: that sounds weird because the text lines broke well for me.Did u change the width to 100% as i did ? but that would make you lose the fixed size.In that case , You could change the 40% to size You actualy need,without any extra space

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might attempt to implement this. I'm setting the left and right heights using jQuery. I also tweaked the markup a bit to use IDs instead of classes for elements like left and right, so the jQuery selector will be faster.

**CSS:**

```
    /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
    * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

    html,
    body
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    #public
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

    #public #container
    {
        min-width:1050px;
    }

    #public #left
    {
        float:left;
        width:40%;
    }

    #public #left .content
    {
        margin-top:20px;
        width:365px;
        float:right;
    }

    #public #left #logo img
    {
        max-width:100%;
        background-color:#e5e5e5;
    }

    #public #left #platforms
    {
        background-color:#888;
        height:30px;
    }

    #public #right
    {
        float:left;
        width:60%;
        background-image:url(images/bg_public.jpg);
    }

    #public #right .content
    {
        height:100%;
        padding:20px;
        background:url(images/public-right-shadow.png) no-repeat left top;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="public">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
      <div class="content">
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="platforms"><img src="images/supported-platforms.png" /></div>
        <div id="copy">&copy; all right reserved 2012</div>
      </div>
    </div><!--.left-->
    <div id="right">
      <div class="content">
      Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. Right column here. 
      </div>
    </div><!--.right-->
  </div><!--#container-->
</div><!--#public-->
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var WindowResize = function(){
        var WindowHeight = $(window).height();
        $('#left, #right').css('height', WindowHeight);

    }

    WindowResize();
    $(window).bind('resize', WindowResize);
});
```